# Platforms other than Wattpad to post your work?

Tags: fiction

I’m looking to eventually share my book online for others to read. I was paging through Wattpad and it just isn’t necessarily the place I’d like my work to be. Just reading through a few random stories on there and it just seems like a ton of teenagers writing poorly constructed fanfic. Not serious writers looking to get their work out there. I’m not saying everyone on there is bad but it’s just not the platform I’d like to use. What other places are there like Wattpad that’s perhaps geared for more experienced writers?